# NetworkManager doesn't start automatically

Tags: ubuntu, networkmanager

On one of the machines that I have Ubuntu installed NetworkManager has to be started manually by me (`sudo NetworkManager start` - as far as I remember). It is a bit inconvenient to be forced to start NetworkManager every time by hand. I think it started working like that after I bought myself a wireless router and stopped using direct PPPoE connection.

On all other machines it works as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. I've managed to fix the issue. I've tried to compare as many configuration files related to networking as possible.

1. A change in `NetworkManager`: I had to change `managed` (in `ifupdown` section) to `false`. That didn't fix the issue itself, but may be connected.
2. Having a look at http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager I've changed my `/etc/network/interfaces` to be exactly as the one on my second machine (which works without any problems). My `interfaces` file was:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

and I've changed it to:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

And now it works! I hope it will help others having similar issue (especially when dealing with PPPoE in the past).